# Install Windows Authentication for IIS 7 on Windows 7 Enterprise?

Tags: command-line, iis, windows-authentication

Is it possible to install Windows Authentication for IIS 7 on Windows 7 Enterprise through the Command Line? and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Go to the command prompt and type:

```
PKGMGR.EXE /iu:IIS-WindowsAuthentication
```

Comment: Thanks, This is partially correct.. In Windows 7 I had to use DISM instead.

Comment: Are you sure / Did you run in an elevated command prompt? This worked for me... But glad you got it working anyway.